# Не исполняется subprocess из под планировщика задач python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

subprocess не исполняется из планировщика совсем. То есть для проверки прописал следующее

```
f = open('/test.txt','w')
f.write('test')
f.close()
 
p=subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", "/269.mp4", "-c:v", "libwebp", "-vf", "fps=1/300,scale=-2:min'(ih,700)'", "-vsync", "vfr", "/img%01d.webp"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 
f = open('/errors.txt','ab')
f.write(p.stderr.read())
f.close()
```

Файл test.txt создался, значит ошибок в скрипте нет, а вот файл errors.txt его нет. Хотя он должен быть в любом случаи. Будь это ошибка в процессе(команде), либо логи. Получается что команда что в subprocess она вовсе не исполняет.

Например если запускать скрипт вручную все работает и файл errors.txt содержит процесс.

**Если все идет своим чередом errors**

```
    ffmpeg version db2935c Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffmpeg-static/target --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/ffmpeg-static/target/include --extra-ldflags=-L/ffmpeg-static/target/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm -lz' --extra-ldexeflags=-static --bindir=/ffmpeg-static/bin --enable-pic --enable-ffplay --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libass --enable-libfribidi --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100

  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.62.100
  Duration: 00:09:00.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 795 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], 661 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> webp (libwebp))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: webp (libwebp), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.0033 fps, 0.0033 tbn, 0.0033 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libwebp
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    1 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=74.3x    
frame=    1 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=66.1x    
frame=    1 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=59.5x    
frame=    1 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=54.1x    
frame=    1 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=49.7x    
frame=    1 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=45.9x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=42.6x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=39.8x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=37.3x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=35.1x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=33.2x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=31.4x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=29.8x    
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=28.4x    
frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:10:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=53.6x    
frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:10:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=51.3x    
frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:10:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=49.2x    
frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:10:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=47.3x    
frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:10:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=45.5x    
frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:10:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=45.4x    
video:34kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

**На случаи ошибки(не найден файл) errors**

```
ffmpeg version db2935c Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffmpeg-static/target --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/ffmpeg-static/target/include --extra-ldflags=-L/ffmpeg-static/target/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm -lz' --extra-ldexeflags=-static --bindir=/ffmpeg-static/bin --enable-pic --enable-ffplay --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libass --enable-libfribidi --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
/************/269.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Что самое интересное. Весь код, что ниже subprocess, если скрипт запускает система. Он уже не исполняется. Толи система не читает и пропускает, толи что еще.

Не знаю как еще смотреть логи в том случаи если крипт был запущен системой и посмотреть результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное, что приходит на ум - возможно у системы не хватает прав на выполнение команды в subprocess. Когда вы запускаете скрипт руками - вы делаете это от администратора? Вероятно вам стоит попробовать как-то "наделить" задачу в планировщике правами администратора.

P.S. Это лишь догадка.

Update:

А почему бы не попробовать сделать так:

```
f = open('/test.txt','w')
f.write('test')
f.close()

try:
    p=subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", "/269.mp4", "-c:v", "libwebp", "-vf", "fps=1/300,scale=-2:min'(ih,700)'", "-vsync", "vfr", "/img%01d.webp"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except Exception as e:
    f = open('/exception.txt', 'w', encoding = "utf-8")
    f.write(str(e))
    f.close()
 
f = open('/errors.txt','ab')
f.write(p.stderr.read())
f.close()
```

И не посмотреть в файл exception.txt?

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'

Comment: Буду разбираться в чем тут дело, пока не нашел где толком копать

Answer (score 0):

Укажите переменную PATH в планировщике

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Перенаправьте вывод питона в /tmp/error2.txt

```
0 0 * * * python.... > /tmp/error2.txt
```

И прочтите там исключение